# Linux shell jobs "No such job"

Tags: linux, shell

mytest.sh

```
./mytest &
fg 1
```

```
sh mytest.sh
```

mytest.sh: 2: fg: No such job: 1

Comment: Job control is turned off by default in scripts. `fg` isn't _expected_ to work in the first place.

Comment: ...while the error message you have is a bit different than the one described in some duplicates, that's presumably a `sh`-vs-`bash` difference. Job control being off-by-default in noninteractive interpreters is part of the POSIX spec, so it applies to all POSIX shells, not just bash.

Comment: the job id format should be `%job_id`, try `fg %1`

Answer (score 0):

`fg` is a job control feature. Job control is turned off by default in scripts (and bash -- like other shells -- can be compiled to not have any interactive-only features at all; in NixOS, for example, this is the difference between the `bash` and `bashInteractive` packages -- so while in *many* Linux distros job control can be explicitly turned on in a script, this isn't true in all of them).

Wait by PID instead:

```
./mytest & mytest_pid=$!
wait "$mytest_pid"
```